# How much i can earn from admob with 10 active users?

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, facebook-ads

If my 10 active users make 10,000 impressions on rewarded video ads (only impressions or,not click), per day, how much i can earn from admob?(earnings per day)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no overall answer. It depends on quite some factors:

- are your users skipping the video or watching the whole ad?
- from which region do your users come frome?
- how is the click through rate (ppl that actually download/buy stuff shown in the ad)

and a couple more.

So it can range from a couple of $ to hundreds of dollars.

[see here for more info](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3016008?hl=en#:%7E:text=Effective%20cost%20per%20thousand%20impressions,Next%3A%20Estimated%20earnings)

Comment: Please do not answer Off-topic questions this will only encourage a mess on the SO.